# circular link with php gives error of cpu usage beyond threshold

Tags: php, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to write a circular link list program with PHP as below,

```
class node {

  public $data;
  public $next;

  public function __construct($item){
    $this->data = $item;
    $this->next = NULL;
  }

}

class linklist{
  public $head=NULL;
  public $tail = NULL;
  Public static $count=0;


  public function insertAtFirst($item){
    if($this->head == NULL){
      $this->head = new node($item);
    }
    else {
      $last = $this->head;

      while ($last->next != NULL && self::$count>1) {
        $last = $last->next;
      }
      $this->tail = $last;
      $tmp = new node($item);
      $tmp->next = $this->head;
      $this->head = $tmp;      
      $this->tail->next = $tmp;
    }
    self::$count++;
  }
}

$linklist = new linklist();
$linklist->insertAtFirst(1)
$linklist->insertAtFirst(13);
```

In my above code for circular link list, I have to give link of the first node into the last node,

for that, I have used code,

```
$this->tail->next = $tmp;
```

after that, it gives me an error of CPU usage beyond the threshold.

If I comment that line then code is working but it does not give link of first not into the last node.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: After making the list circular `$last->next != NULL` will  be true for all elements, hence the infinite loop

Comment: then what should be condition in while loop , please let me know.

Comment: You don't need the loop at all. When inserting the first element, set both head and tail to the new (and only) element. Then when inserting the next element, you already have tail and don't need to search it. The code for inserting the first element should also let the element's next point to itself (at least that would be my understanding of 'circular' for a list consisting of one element only)

Comment: I have removed the loop now

Comment: my code in else part is like: $tmp = new node($item);
      $tmp->next = $this->head;
      $this->tail->next = $tmp;
      $this->head = $tmp;

Comment: still having problem of same

Comment: hmm, IMHO that looks good. If you don't have a loop, there shouldn't be an opportunity for the CPU to choke anymore?

Comment: if I comment this line :$this->tail->next = $tmp; , then it works, but We can not link tail with head

Comment: Then you certainly have some other code not shown here which loops through the list and fails to detect that it is circular.

Comment: Here, in my question I have added my all the code which I have try for circular linklist